# Oracle: character to number conversion e

Tags: sql, plsql

I am using Oracle SQL Developer. I am a student. When I do an insert to a table with a parameter `PRICE NUMBER(5,2)` and I put in the insert `12.23` for example, I can execute this. However, when I do a procedure with this `NUMBER ( I put PRODUCTS.PRICE%TYPE )` and a do execute `INSERT_PRODUCT(12.23)` show the next error...

> PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1
>       06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>       *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>                  occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>                  assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>                  attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>                  declared NUMBER(2).

The problem is PRECIO and IVA, in the table they are `NUMBER(x,x)`

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS
(
    OID_P NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    PRECIO NUMBER(6,2),
    IVA NUMBER(3,2), CHECK(IVA>=0 AND IVA<=1),
    CODIGO VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONCEPTO VARCHAR(20)
);
```

The procedure...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTAR_PRODUCTO
(
     W_PRECIO IN PRODUCTOS.PRECIO%TYPE,
     W_IVA IN PRODUCTOS.IVA%TYPE,
     W_CODIGO IN PRODUCTOS.CODIGO%TYPE,
     W_CONCEPTO IN PRODUCTOS.CONCEPTO%TYPE
)
    IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (PRECIO, IVA, CODIGO, CONCEPTO)
        VALUES (W_PRECIO, W_IVA, W_CODIGO, W_CONCEPTO);
    END;
```

I call with execute

```
INSERTAR_PRODUCTO(12.23, 0.15, '123122', 'chandal');
```

I don't know how to remove this problem.  Sorry for my English.  Thank you.

Comment: Pls show us your stored procedure. Thanks

Comment: I have it put yet

Comment: when you execute this stored proc execute INSERT_PRODUCT(12.23); w_iva is null.  Try this one: execute INSERT_PRODUCT(12.23, 34.56)

Comment: yes I had put all the parameters execute INSERTAR_PRODUCTo(12.23, 34.56, '123122', 'chandal'); but the console show this error

Comment: try to change your stored procedure to this: INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (PRECIO, IVA, CODIGO, CONCEPTO) VALUES(to_number(W_PRECIO), to_number(W_IVA), W_CODIGO, W_CONCEPTO);   this is to ensure that the datatype is number. It may not be an efficient solution but try it first.

Comment: When I run your code I get `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PRODUCTOS"."OID_P")`. But when I supply a valid for `OID_P` everything is fine. There must be something else. Which tool do you use to call the stored procedure? You would need a `exec` or something similar in order to call it.

Comment: I have a trigger that generate authomaticly the OID_P - I only put execute INSERTAR_PRODUCTO(12.12 ,0.14 ,'323125' ,'Camiseta');

Comment: With a right value on primary key your code runs for me without problems.

Comment: maybe you need to `INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (OID_P , PRECIO, IVA, CODIGO, CONCEPTO)
        VALUES (SEQ_OID_P.NextVal, W_PRECIO, W_IVA, W_CODIGO, W_CONCEPTO);` use a sequence for primary key instead of trigger?  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm  Sequences will not suffer from race conditions that a select max+1 could.

Comment: ok, thank you everybody I am trying all the thing you say me.